# Nuxt.js Server Side Rendering: Data doesn't get updated after starting the server

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo, server-side-rendering

I'm facing an issue with Nuxt.js and Apollo not updating my page's content with the latest from my API source. The server gets 'stuck' on the version when it was started, unless I restart the server the data doesn't get updated. I've searched on Github for any similar issues or even here and couldn't find anything.

I'm using `"@nuxtjs/apollo": "^4.0.1-rc.5"` with `"nuxt": "^2.14.12"`.

When using `nuxt dev` mode I have no issues, my page data is correctly fetched, and if I change some of its data on my API and then reload the page, the data gets updated.

Nuxt is set to target the server, so it's not building static files.

When I'm in SSR with `nuxt build && nuxt start` I have the page displays the right data initially, so SSR seems to work. However, if I edit my API's data and then reload the page I don't get the page content updated but rather the version I had when I ran `nuxt start`.

If I stop and restart the application and then reload the page, I have the right updated data show up. I feel like this might be a caching-related issue.

Here's my apollo config that gets loaded into Nuxt:

```
import { InMemoryCache, IntrospectionFragmentMatcher } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import introspectionQueryResultData from './graphql.schema.json'

const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
  introspectionQueryResultData
})

const cache = InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher })

export default function (ctx) {
  return {
    httpEndpoint: MY_ENDPOINT,
    cache
  }
}
```

I need the Fragment Matcher in order to use GraphQL fragments and generate the types with codegen, my code base is in Typescript. This works like a charm in dev mode but might be the reason why it doesn't work in SSR even though I couldn't find why.

On my Vue component to render my page here's a sample configuration:

```
apollo: {
  page: {
    prefetch: true,
    query: queryPage, // imported GraphQL query with .gql file
    variables() {
      return {
        id: 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I do not understand why my server isn't refetching the data after being started. I tried to debug without success in the Nuxt generated server files.

How can I get my page to fetch the data when loaded, without having to restart the application after each update on my API's content?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing a similar issue. Downgrading to `"@nuxtjs/apollo": "4.0.1-rc.1"` works.